# Using regular exp in oracle to remove a group of codes

Tags: regex, oracle

i've a column in my Oracle table and it has many values with a group of codes as below :

(5000311520) smart tv 40 inch + cinema/internet(high-speed)

now i'm going to remove the code : (5000311520)

it means the result should be : smart tv 40 inch + cinema/internet(high-speed)

anybody can help me?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select without the number code at the start :

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(Comments,'^\([0-9]+\)\s*','') from Table1
```

Explaining the regex:

```
^       : start of the text
\(      : a literal '(' character
[0-9]+  : 1 or more digits from 0 to 9
\)      : a literal ')' character
\s*     : 0 or more whitespaces (spaces, tabs, linefeeds, ...)
```

And to strip the code from the column values permanently?
You can use such regex also in the where clause:

```
update Table1
set Comments = REGEXP_REPLACE(Comments,'^\([0-9]+\)\s*','')
where REGEXP_LIKE(Comments,'^\([0-9]+\)')
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the part you are interested in you can try the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(yourColumn, '\([[:digit:]]+\) (.*)', '(\1)') AS result 
  FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: thanks a lot,it is working with :                    
REGEXP_REPLACE(comments, '\([[:digit:]]+\)', '')

Comment: @arash That's good to hear. If this answer solved your problem you can accept it with the green button under the score of this answer to show other users that you found your solution and don't need any more help with this request. It also awards a bit of reputation to you and the person who wrote the answer you accepted.